# calling my CreateFile Method -> An object refference is required for non-static field

Tags: c#, static, static-methods

I'm new to C#. This is a small example for my problem. How can I call a method inside a static method, in this case `Main`? This is the error

> An object reference is required for non-static field...

What is wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"c:\";
            string filename = "lsdfkjg.txt";
            CreateFile(path, filename);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void CreateDirectory(string path, string filename)
        {
            string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        }

        public void CreateFile(string path, string filename)
        {
            string pathstring = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathstring))
            {
                System.IO.File.Create(pathstring);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: CreateFile(path, filename); in the Main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your method CreateFile static

```
public void CreateFile(string path, string filename)
```

to

```
public static void CreateFile(string path, string filename)
```